# What should i do to access member variable of an object?

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    class c1{
        int i;

        public:
        int bv;
        void seti(int i){
            c1::i=i;
                        }
        int geti(){return i;}
        int accessbv(c1 inst1);
    };
    int c1::accessbv (c1 inst1){
        cout<<"here in the base accesing inst1's bv"<<inst1.bv;
    }
```

I want to access inst1's member variable bv.The above code doesnt compile. What should i do?
Also i have observed one thing ,if the class c1's defintion is global it is working the way i want it to. Why is it behaving this way?

Comment: "doesn't compile" well, what's the error message ?

Comment: You cannot define one function inside another function. Just move everything outside `main`.

Comment: You can't define functions in functions...

Comment: @Wndrr  [Error] qualified-id in declaration before '(' token and  [Error] expected '}' at end of input

Comment: @BoPersson i would like to know more about no function inside another function thing

Comment: @rimiro - It is just a language rule in C and C++, all functions are separate and cannot be nested. Other languages, like Pascal, allows it - so it varies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just because the class is local, doesn't mean the rules for defining functions change. The C++ standard even goes as far as to state it explicitly.

[[class.local]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/class.local#2), emphasis mine:

> An enclosing function has no special access to members of the local
>   class; it obeys the usual access rules (Clause [class.access]). **Member
>   functions of a local class shall be defined within their class
>   definition, if they are defined at all.**

"The rules" mentioned above is simply what is stated in the function definition related section of the standard, [[dcl.fct.def.general]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/dcl.fct.def.general#2):

> ... A function shall be defined only in namespace or class scope.

And that's it.

Comment: can you clarify the first statement "An enclosing function has no special access to members of the local class; it obeys the usual access rules (Clause [class.access])."  and add something about no functions allowed inside another function rule.

Comment: @rimiro - The first sentance has nothing to do with your question. The "rule" I just quoted.

Comment: i have one confusion :  Are namespaces defined by the functions?

Comment: @rimiro - I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on StoryTeller's answser here is an example of explaining what it means by your comment to his answer:

> can you clarify the first statement "An enclosing function has no special access to members of the local class; it obeys the usual access rules (Clause [class.access])." and add something about no functions allowed inside another function rule.

```
void someFunc() {
    class foo {
    private:
        int x;
    public:
        int getX() const { return x; }
        void setX( int val ) { x = val; }
    };
}
```

Here `foo` is a local class that is declared in `someFunc()`. The scope or body of `someFunc` has no means of accessing `foo`'s internals. Since the above functions are declared & defined within `foo`'s scope this is valid.

Trying to do this:

```
void someFunc() {
    class boo {
    private:
        int x;
    public:
        int getX() const;
        void setX( int val );
    };

    // These are illegal. You can not define a function within a function
    // even when they belong to a class.

    // These two functions can not be defined here because this is
    // considered re-declaring them out side of their class within local scope of a function. 
    // These will give you a compiler error: local function definitions are illegal
    int boo::getX() const { return x; }
    void boo::setX( int val ) { x = val; }
}
```

Results in a compiler error.

Here `someFunc()` has no way of accessing `boo`'s scope through its scope resolution operator for its member variables. It can not access `boo::x`.

It is illegal to declare a function within a function this can not be done because of the stack pointer for function scope. Functions are not like while & for loops or switch statements which can be nested. A function's scope is a single translation unit within an object file after it's been compiled. You can have an empty scope within a function as that is valid, but you can not declare - define a function within another.